# Getting swiftmailer to work

Tags: php, html, forms, swiftmailer

Im new to PHP and trying desperately to get a simple contact form on my website to work using swiftmailer. So i have the library installed to the right location, and the form opens like this:

```
 <form action="mailhandler_girls.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

then in my "mailhandler_girls.php" file i have the following:

```
 <?php

$_SESSION["post"] = $_POST; 

$name = $_POST["Name"]; $email = $_POST["Email"]; $phone = $_POST["Phone"]; $dob = $_POST['DOBDay'] ."\t" .$_POST['DOBMonth'] ."\t" .$_POST['DOBYear'];$address = $_POST['AddressLine1'] ."\n" .$_POST['AddressLine2'] ."\n" .$_POST['PostCode'];$experience = $_POST["Experience"];$height = $_POST["Height"]; $size = $_POST["DressSize"];$bra = $_POST["Bra"];$waist = $_POST["Waist"];$hipwidest = $_POST["HipWidest"];$bicep = $_POST["Bicep"];$thigh = $_POST["Thigh"];$shoe = $_POST["Shoe"];    

require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk', 25)
->setUsername('user@example.com')
->setPassword('test')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Be A Model application: Girls') 

// Set the From address with an associative array
->setFrom(array('$email' => '$name'))

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo(array('holla@emilekelly.com', 'contact@emilekelly.com' => 'contact test'))

// Give it a body
->setBody('Name: ' .$name ."\n"
.'Email: ' .$email ."\n"
.'Phone: ' .$phone ."\n"
.'Address: ' .$address ."\n"
.'DOB: ' .$dob ."\n"
.'Experience: ' .$experience ."\n"
.'Height: ' .$height ."\n"
.'Dress Size: ' .$size ."\n"
.'Bra: ' .$bra ."\n"
.'Waist: ' .$waist ."\n"
.'Hip at Widest: ' .$hipwidest ."\n"
.'Bicep: ' .$bicep ."\n"
.'Thigh: ' .$thigh ."\n"
.'Shoe Size: ' .$shoe ."\n" )


// And optionally an alternative body
->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html');
// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);




?>
```

Nothing happens. Im sure what im doing wrong is obvious, but im lost in it. I have been using the documentation, which has got me this far, but still stuck.

I just want to get this basic version working then worry about elaborating with image attachments. Im also confused about the SMTP transport thing. Surely not a good idea to have the username and password just sitting there in a file on the net like that?

Comment: so without SMTP username and password how can you use it.??

Comment: set `php_ini('display_errors', true);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, dump information: `var_dump($result);`, if you have bug, we'll find him.

Comment: What, how? Sorry, as i said i am knew to all this..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since you are new to this one , try executing the php file first with pre defined values instead of $_POST from commandline .

If you are on windows, you would have to traverse through your directories and do this:

```
php.exe mailhandler_girls.php
```

If you are on linux do this:

```
php5 mailhandler_girls.php
```

This would elegantly output the errors if any .

The error message will indicate if there is a problem with your credentials , problem with encryption or whatever it may be .